# Runtime-error 1004 when trying to code saveas

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

So the code below functioned with out any issues before. Basically, I get this doc emailed to me, the code runs to extract the needed data, saves to the workbook to the specified file pathway to the specified filename, and the next part of the code puts all the data gathered on a summary doc.

Today, I tried to add an alert message box so that if certain conditions were met , a message to the user would be provided when there was an attempt to save. When I did that, I began getting a Runtime 1004 error and still get it even though I have removed the beforesave event on the worksheet. It was using ActiveWorkbook... and then I changed it to ThisWorkbook after reading about how ActiveWorkbook can cause errors.

I don't know what the file name will be when I get these docs, and would like to simply have the doc save and apply to specified file name when I run the macro. Any ideas on why I am suddenly getting this error?

```
'saves incident report to incident report folder
    ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=("C:\Users\ashley.graham\Field Agent Folder\Incident Reports\Test folder\Test Incident report folder\" & IncidentReport & AgentName & ".xlsm")
```

Comment: What is the content of `IncidentReport` and `AgentName` ? And what is the exact error message?

Comment: Before the whole line was highlighted so I'm not sure. IncidentReport and AgentName are string variables. I want those two variables together to make the filename when it's saved.

Comment: I assume that the content of the vars contain invalid characters - or there is another issue the final file name (typo in the folder name, access denied etc). For this I am asking for the exact error message - the number (1004) is not sufficient.

Comment: FWIW the parentheses are redundant. @FunThomas 1004 is the ever-so-helpful "Application-defined error" message.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon: I know. But the desciption may change. If I say `saveAs "x/y.xlsx"`, it says *cannot access the file*, while saving a xlsm-file with `saveAs "xy.xlsx"` it says *This extension cannot be used...*

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook` refers to whatever workbook is currently active. If you mean to work against the workbook this code is written in, use `ThisWorkbook`. And for the love of all that is good don't dereference `ActiveWorkbook` from the `Workbooks` collection as suggested below!

Comment: Oh, so perhaps this wasn't solved correctly. The error I got was Method 'Saveas' of object' _workbook'failed. Sorry, I thought I included the entire error.

Comment: I understand now! When the error is returned, there is no data in the incidentreport and agentname variables. At least for now, but if I get it out of the blue again, I'll know what to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
Dim wb As Workbook

Set wb = Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name)

    wb.SaveAs Filename:=("C:\Users\ashley.graham\Field Agent Folder\Incident Reports\Test folder\Test Incident report folder\" & IncidentReport & AgentName & ".xlsm")
```

Comment: I made these changes and got a compile error: Variable not defined. I added dim wb as workbook and then got another Compile error: Type mismatch with "Name" highlighted. Did I set the wrong variable type?

Comment: @IRENE: What is the idea to **open** the active workbook?

Comment: you are right - you can use without the .open... :)

Comment: The OP wants to save `thisWorkbook`, not `activeWorkbook`. And there is no use to assign one Workbook object to another before saving

Comment: With open removes the error but doesn't save to the specified workbook name. When I just put set wb= Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.name) I get a Type Mismatch error.

Comment: I forgot to replace 'open' with '.name'. When I did that, it works fine. Thanks so much! Any idea why it was working and this stopped?

Comment: As @FunThomas already mentioned, `Workbooks(ActiveWorkbook.Name)` is just a complicated way of saying `ActiveWorkbook`. Just like you could always replace `1` in a calculation with `2-1` or `2/2` - it's still correct, just not as direct.

Comment: @MsAgentM as others have pointed out, the whole `Set wb =` thing is useless and redundant. `ThisWorkbook.SaveAs` is what you want to call.

Comment: I had ThisWorkbook.Saveas before and before that had ActiveWorkbook.Saveas. Both return the 1004 runtime error Method 'Saveas' of object' _workbook'failed. That's why I posted here. Its weird because before today, this code worked fine. I didn't have an issue until I added an event change to alert a message box before saving if a condition was met.

Comment: You guys were right about the redundancy. It appears the error is returned when the variables has no data. Thanks for the help, I understand this portion of the coding much better now.